# Python Regex with split Method

Tags: python, regex, csv

I am trying to create a list from a csv file. However, I'm having a tough time using the split method because some of the attributes in the csv file has comma's that are within parenthesis. for example:

```
csv file:

500,403,34,"hello there, this attribute has a comma in it",567
```

So for example, when I iterate through the file:

```
for line in f:
    fields = line.split(",")

fields = ['500','403','34','"hello there','this attribute has a comma in it"','567']
```

How can I get it to look like this:

```
fields = ['500','403','34','"hello there, this attribute has a comma in it"','567']
```

I would like to use Regex for this, but if there is an easier way I'd love to hear it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
x='500,403,34,"hello there, this attribute has a comma in it",567'
print re.split(r""",(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*)*[^"]*$)""",x)
```

Output : `['500', '403', '34', '"hello there, this attribute has a comma in it"', '567']`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [existing CSV package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). Example:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            print ', '.join(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSV module is the easiest way to go:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        print row
```

For input `input.csv`:

```
500,403,34,"hello there, this attribute has a comma in it",567
500,403,34,"hello there this attribute has no comma in it",567
500,403,34,"hello there, this attribute has multiple commas, in, it",567
```

The output is:

```
['500', '403', '34', 'hello there, this attribute has a comma in it', '567']
['500', '403', '34', 'hello there this attribute has no comma in it', '567']
['500', '403', '34', 'hello there, this attribute has multiple commas, in, it', '567']
```